# Is it more efficient to do a single SQL SELECT with joins vs several smaller SQLs?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, refactoring

I have code that uses long `SELECT` statements that usually `LEFT JOIN` various tables on top of each other using some kind of `id`s or `key`s to join the data.

The result of this SQL is then entered into a PHP class construct.  Result can contain for example

- curve coefficients
- product parameters
- test data

The code I have is not terribly well structured so I am thinking to instead of one long `SQL` query, to split it up into several (i.e. 3 in this case) smaller simple SQL `SELECT`s.  Benefits are that the code will be cleaner, easier to understand and can be better refactored into smaller more meaningful classes and functions.

But before I start to dismantling a large number of similar-looking SQL statements, I wanted to check if from performance standpoint it will make sense to break up the SQL.  Because, alternatively I can keep the long SQL as is and still be able to refactor my code into more meaningful classes and functions, but just differently.

**Question**:  In the end, considering how PHP and MySql work together, is there any measurable benefit to use longer SQLs with multiple joins over several calls to shorter SQLs (possibly without any joins)?

Comment: Define "more efficient"? Usually you test a hypothesis by running benchmark tests on your data on your hardware. The winner is not always obvious. The solution without a `JOIN` is often faster, but it really depends on a number of factors that are difficult to identify from your description.

Comment: In terms of coding, one query would require less effort.

Comment: good point I will need to run a benchmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my benchmark

- 10,000 x execution of a long SQL statement takes 1.5 seconds
- 10,000 x execution of equivalent shorter SQL statements takes 2.43 secods

Long SQL wins, most likely due to PHP processing more lines of code in general, for my specific case.

Comment: while other answer is more general & more helpful perhaps in a variety of situations, I chose to accept this one as it answered it for me with real data for my case.

Answer (score 1):

As with most things MySQL, it depends. You'd really need to test to find out.

There's an overhead cost for each SQL query that gets submitted to the database (overhead of parsing, preparing the query, executing, preparing results, responding to fetches, cleaning up). And that's why a boatload of round trips to the database with little queries (like, a really tight loop, getting one row per query), is a lot less efficient than a single query that returns all the rows.

On the other hand, up until MySQL 5.6, the only join method the optimizer used was nested loops. If there aren't suitable indexes, or misleading statistics...

A "large" query (i.e. one that involves dozens of tables and millions and millions of rows) can be problematic in terms of performance.

But the database server usually performs adequately with normal join operations, on reasonably sized and appropriately indexed sets. And the join operation on the database server is often more efficient than an equivalent operation performed by code running on an application server.

**Q:** Is there a measurable difference?

**A:** In theory, there can be.  (In theory, there's no difference between theory and practice. In practice, there is.)

The benefit of running one query versus thousands of queries is less overhead, and the difference can be measured.

The downside of one query is that the query can require MySQL to do so much work that the performance becomes glacial, and we can sometimes get better efficiency by breaking the query into manageable chunks. We don't usually notice the overhead of a couple of query executions... it's when we're into the thousands of database roundtrips that we run into performance and scalability issues.

To really find out, since you are already thinking about breaking up the query, go ahead and break up the query into the individual queries you are planning to run, and test.

(I've focused on the efficiency from the database server side of things, not on the performance of the application server... I've also been thinking in terms of the database server being on one host, with network connection between the app server and the database... millisecond network roundtrips start to add up when you get up into the tens of thousands of roundtrips.)